# Generate PHP code that would generate target XML with XMLWriter

Tags: c#, php, xml, code-generation

Now, it's not hard to create XML files from PHP with the `XMLWriter` like this:

```
$objWriter->startDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8', 'yes');

// Data
$objWriter->startElement("Relationships");
$objWriter->writeAttribute("xmlns", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships");

$objWriter->startElement("Relationship");
$objWriter->writeAttribute("Id", "rId1");
$objWriter->writeAttribute("Type", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/chartUserShapes");
$objWriter->writeAttribute("Target", "../drawings/drawing" . $drawingNum . ".xml");
$objWriter->endElement(); // Relationship

$objWriter->endElement(); // Relationships

$result = $objWriter->getData();
```

However, what if I already have a "template" XML file (let's say abount 30+ lines) that I want to generate via PHP like this, with few attributes here and there computed by the PHP script.

Now I could go and write `startElement`, `writeAttribute` and `endElement` for abount half an hour, or I could:

1) Generate such code autommaticly, use some program that parses XML (Java, C#, PHP, whatever), read the tags and attributes, and generate corresponging PHP code that would in turn generate the original XML. This would help a lot.

2) Just cancel the `<?php` tag with `?>` and dump the XML directly, only adding `<?php echo $value ?>` where needed, then use some trickery to not write this to stdout, but store it inside a string instead. This would be acceptable if that trickery didn't invole putting this inside it's own script and getting the result via curl.

So what do you think is the best option to go with? I need this for exporting charts with PHPExcel, a lot the stuff I need just isn't supported by PHPExcel, especially in the chart area, so I just look at the desired XML files and generate them myself.

*EDIT:*

This is my progress so far with code generation in C#:

```
private static void doWork(string filename, Func<string, string> onElementStart, Func<string, string> onElementEnd, Func<string, string, string> onAttribute)
{
    using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create("file:///" + filename))
    {
        using (StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(@"c:\kajacx\other\troll_excel5\output.php"))
        {
            // Parse the file and display each of the nodes.
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                switch (reader.NodeType)
                {
                    case XmlNodeType.Element:
                        file.WriteLine(onElementStart(reader.Name));
                        break;
                    case XmlNodeType.Attribute:
                        file.WriteLine(onAttribute(reader.Name, reader.Value));
                        break;
                    case XmlNodeType.EndElement:
                        file.WriteLine(onElementEnd(reader.Name));
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Works pretty good, except it doesnt parse attributes (like in `<tag attrName="attValue" />`, but still better than nothing. Anyone know how to make the attributes work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike child elements, attributes are loaded at the same time the element node itself is loaded.  Thus, when `reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element`, you can use [`XmlReader.MoveToNextAttribute()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.movetonextattribute.aspx) to cycle through the attributes, finally moving back to the element with [`XmlReader.MoveToElement()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.movetoelement.aspx):

```
private static void DoWork(XmlReader reader, Action<string> onElementStart, Action<string> onElementEnd, Action<string, string> onAttribute)
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        switch (reader.NodeType)
        {
            case XmlNodeType.Element:
                onElementStart(reader.Name);
                if (reader.HasAttributes)
                {
                    while (reader.MoveToNextAttribute())
                    {
                        onAttribute(reader.Name, reader.Value);
                    }
                    // Move the reader back to the element node.
                    reader.MoveToElement();
                }
                if (reader.IsEmptyElement)
                {
                    // Do something special for empty elements?  
                }
                break;
            case XmlNodeType.Attribute:
                onAttribute(reader.Name, reader.Value);
                break;
            case XmlNodeType.EndElement:
                onElementEnd(reader.Name);
                break;
        }
    }
}

private static void doWork(string filename, Func<string, string> onElementStart, Func<string, string> onElementEnd, Func<string, string, string> onAttribute)
{
    using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create("file:///" + filename))
    {
        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"c:\kajacx\other\troll_excel5\output.php"))
        {
            DoWork(reader, writer, onElementEnd, onElementEnd, onAttribute);
        }
    }
}

private static void DoWork(XmlReader reader, TextWriter writer, Func<string, string> onElementStart, Func<string, string> onElementEnd, Func<string, string, string> onAttribute)
{
    DoWork(reader,
        (s) => writer.WriteLine(onElementStart(s)),
        (s) => writer.WriteLine(onElementEnd(s)),
        (s1, s2) => writer.WriteLine(onAttribute(s1, s2))
    );
}
```

(Here I refactored your code a bit to make testing easier.)